# How can I search SQL database using long sentences

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

My app have a table for Blog and News, i am able to perform a normal search in database with the LIKE keyword.

Example: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name LIKE '% JOHN %'

My task now is to retrieve records by searchnig with long sentence which may be news or blog title, blog post tags to use in retrieving related posts or user search from sql database but using the above query does not produce any result.
Please what technique do i need to apply? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a full-text search index.It should be a functionality of your SGBD. If you use SQL Server then you can activate the service, configure and use it.

Comment: Pls how do i go about this task?

Comment: Hi, please have a look there : [sqlserver](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks.. I have successfully implemented it, useful link

Comment: My pleasure @PrinceTegaton